# Php - When processes are executed

Tags: php, performance, optimization

I've this:

```
class A {
  public function __construct()
    include 'file.php';
  }
  bla bla...
  bla bla...
  bla bla...
  bla bla...
  bla bla...
  bla bla...
  bla bla...
}
new A();
```

The question is:
file.php is a very big data.file and I wanna know if it's loaded when PHP reads construct function or when construct function is called with "new A()";

It' the same for others processes?

It's the same for Javascript?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

`new A()` is when that include will be evaluated.

It will happen for every instance of `A` you create.

If you wanted to ensure that it is only actually included one time, and not every time an `A` object is created, you can change it to `include_once 'file.php';`

See: http://php.net/include_once

Answer (score 1):

With the current code that you display the file will be included everytime you call the constructor.
In other words, each time you call "new A();"

Comment: Mephoros beat me to it with a few seconds :)